# NOT getting output in test.out file using proenv, after executing .p file

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

i am a newbie on progress. i just followed the below kb article, but i am not getting the desired output.
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/How-to-write-a-p-script-to-execute-via-proenv-to-produce-a-stderr-stdout-in-a-file

1. i have created a test.p file with below code:

```
MESSAGE ENTRY (1, "This is a test") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
MESSAGE "Hello there" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
DISPLAY "hello world".
```

2. chmod +x test.p
3. then in proenv i run below command

```
proenv>proenv -b -p test.p > test.out
```

4. i found only below output on test.out file

```
$ cat test.out

      DLC: /opt/progress/117
   WRKDIR: /opt/progress/wrk_117
      OEM: /opt/progress/oemgmt_117
OEMWRKDIR: /opt/progress/wrk_oemgmt_117

Inserting /opt/progress/117/bin to beginning of path and
setting the current directory to /opt/progress/wrk_117.

OpenEdge Release 11.7.5 as of Fri Jun  7 08:29:03 EDT 2019
```

i am not finding, where i have done wrong. Appreciate help on this regards. Thanks.

Comment: 2. The ABL run time performs actual execution, you do not need to make your source file executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
_progres -b -p test.p > test.out
```

or

```
bpro -p test.p > test.out
```

proenv launches a shell with DLC and other variables set. Proenv does not directly execute ABL code.